# iOS - toolbar above keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, keyboard

I have a toolbar (created in storyboard, not in code) in bottom part of the screen. Then there is an UIWebView in the middle and UINavigationBar at top (with UITextField).
When a keyboard appear, I need the toolbar to be above the keyboard.

I have tried

```
[toolBar removeFromSuperview];
textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;
```

This "works", however, UIWebView disappear (or is removed from view as well)... so not a real solution for me.

Using keyboard listeners

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)aNotification
```

with this code

```
NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
```

or with this

```
CGRect    screenRect;
CGRect    windowRect;
CGRect    viewRect;

// determine's keyboard height
screenRect    = [[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
windowRect    = [self.view.window convertRect:screenRect fromWindow:nil];
viewRect      = [self.view        convertRect:windowRect fromView:nil];
CGSize kbSize = viewRect.size;
```

And at the end:

```
CGRect newFrame = toolBar.frame;
newFrame.origin.y = s.bounds.size.height - kbSize.height - newFrame.size.height;
toolBar.frame = newFrame;
```

This "works" as well, but there is also a problem. If I click inside the UIWebView and there is an input, keyborad is shown but `kbSize.height` is different from the keyboard in textField

Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you working with auto layout ?

Comment: Yes, I am using autolayout.

Comment: your webview bottom constraint is with the top of toolbar?

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan Yes